# The Structure of natural numbers is not arithmetic

Tags: logic

I am stuck on an exercise:
We should use the fact that
for all L-formulas $\gamma$(x)  there exists a L-Sentence $\beta$  s.t. N$\models$ $\gamma$('$\beta$') where '$\beta$' means the coding of beta.

The exercise is to show that the set
of Th(N) is not definable in N.
N=(natural Numbers,0,S+,*,<) where S is the map N->N, S(n)=n+1

My idea would be to use 2 different codings to ensure that $\gamma$ cant define the same set, but it seems really wrong to me. Can someone pls explain to me how to solve it

Thanks in advance